# Show that $\lim_{x \rightarrow 1^{-}} (x^ {m+1} \frac {1}{1-x}) =\infty$ for $m \in \Bbb N, m>0$

Tags: limits, functions

I am trying to prove by definition that the limit $ \lim_{x \rightarrow 1^{-}} f(x)=  \lim_{x \rightarrow 1^{-}} (x^ {m+1} \frac {1}{1-x}) =\infty$ for $m \in \Bbb N, m>0$

First I am not sure what the precise definition is for this statement. Is it fair to say for every $M > 0$ there must exist an $\epsilon > 0$ such that whenever
$1-\epsilon < x < 1$ that in fact $f(x) > M$ ?

Then assuming this is true, I would try to work my way backwards and suppose $0<1-x < \frac {1}{M}$ then $\frac {1}{1-x} > M$. I am not sure how to proceed. Hints appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, you want to show that given $M>0$, there exists an $\varepsilon>0$ etc... I would say the "by definition" approach would be to provide a function or list of steps that computes the $\varepsilon$ as a function of $M$.

You correctly assume that we have $1-\varepsilon < x < 1$. Substituting $x = 1-\varepsilon$ in your function gives $f(1-\varepsilon) = \frac{(1-\varepsilon)^{m+1}}{\varepsilon} > M$. Since $\lim_{\varepsilon \to 0^+} \frac{(1-\varepsilon)^{m+1}}{\varepsilon} = \infty$, if you can find a way to solve $\frac{(1-\varepsilon)^{m+1}}{\varepsilon} > M$, you should be done, in my opinion.

Update: You can use any function $\phi(\varepsilon,m)$ where $\frac{(1-\varepsilon)^{m+1}}{\varepsilon} \ge \phi(\varepsilon,m)$ and solve $\phi(\varepsilon,m) > M$, so the key is sometimes to look for a more manageable $\phi(\varepsilon,m)$. Moreover, you can safely assume that $\varepsilon < \frac{1}{2}$, so that $1-\varepsilon > \frac{1}{2}$, giving us, for instance, $$\frac{(1-\varepsilon)^{m+1}}{\varepsilon} > \frac{\frac{1}{2}(1-\varepsilon)^{m}}{\varepsilon} > \cdots > \frac{1}{2^{m+1}}\frac{1}{\varepsilon} = \phi(\varepsilon,m) > M.$$

Comment: Note sure how to isolate $\epsilon$.

Comment: Using the binomial theorem it seems I can come up with the right inequality.